# How can I change a huge file into csv in python

Tags: python, file, csv

I'm a beginner in python. I have a huge text file (hundreds of GB) and I want to convert the file into csv file. In my text file, I know the row delimiter is a string "<><><><><><><>". If a line contains that string, I want to replace it with ". Is there a way to do it without having to read the old file and rewriting a new file.

Normally I thought I need to do something like this:

```
fin = open("input", "r")
fout = open("outpout", "w")
line = f.readline
while line != "":
   if line.contains("<><><><><><><>"):
      fout.writeline("\"")
   else:
      fout.writeline(line)
   line = f.readline
```

but copying hundreds of GB is wasteful. Also I don't know if open will eat lots of memory (does it treat file handler as a stream?)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: an example of the file would be

```
file.txt
<><><><><><><>
abcdefeghsduai 
asdjliwa
1231214 ""
<><><><><><><>
```

would be one row and one column in csv.

Comment: f.readline should be f.readline().  You want to call the method, not copy reference to it.

Comment: Also, file-object doesn't have writeline() method, only write() and writelines() (this means you should append "\n" to your string by yourself if you want a line-break).

Comment: "but copying hundreds of GB is wasteful"  In what way?  You have very little choice but to copy.  What are you imagining as the alternative to a copy?  Please be specific on what you would like to see that isn't a copy.

Comment: @constantin:right, sorry I just made up the code in a hurry, it probably doesn't work.
@S.Lott By wasteful I mean I don't have enough space to spare. I think what I will do is first split the file and the process one file at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

@richard-levasseur

I agree, `sed` seems like the right way to go. Here's a rough cut at what the OP describes:

```
 sed -i -e's/<><><><><><><>/"/g' foo.txt
```

This will do the replacement in-place in the existing `foo.txt`. For that reason, I recommend having the original file under some sort of version control; any of the DVCS should fit the bill.

Comment: Will it also replace <><><><><><><> in the middle of the line?

Comment: It will replace every occurrence with a single `"` character, which is how I interpreted the OP.

Comment: Based on the program provided, it would be more accurate to search for something like ^pattern$ but there were errors in the program so I went with the prose.

Comment: The command line above won't work because -i requires a backup file extension as an argument.  If you don't want a backup, use -i ''.

See http://joemaller.com/2007/09/16/quick-note-about-seds-edit-in-place-option/

Comment: It didn't on my Mac. Is that a GNU thing?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, open() treats the file as a stream, as does readline().  It'll only read the next line.  If you call read(), however, it'll read everything into memory.

Your example code looks ok at first glance.  Almost every solution will require you to copy the file elsewhere.  Its not exactly easy to modify the contents of a file inplace without a 1:1 replacement.

It *may* be faster to use some standard unix utilities (awk and sed most likely), but I lack the unix and bash-fu necessary to provide a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's only wasteful if you don't have disk to spare. That is, fix it when it's a problem. Your solution looks ok as a first attempt.

It's not wasteful of memory because a file handler is a stream.

Answer (score 1):

Reading lines is simply done using a [file iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.next):

```
for line in fin:
       if line.contains("<><><><><><><>"):
           fout.writeline("\"")
```

Also consider the [CSV writer object](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#writer-objects) to write CSV files, e.g:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("some.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Answer (score 1):

With python you will have to create a new file for safety sake, it will cause alot less headaches than trying to write in place.

The below listed reads your input 1 line at a time and buffers the columns (from what I understood of your test input file was 1 row) and then once the end of row delimiter is hit it will write that buffer to disk, flushing manually every 1000 lines of the original file.  This will save some IO as well instead of writing every segment, 1000 writes of 32 bytes each will be faster than 4000 writes of 8 bytes.

```
fin = open(input_fn, "rb")
fout = open(output_fn, "wb")
row_delim = "<><><><><><><>"
write_buffer = []

for i, line in enumerate(fin):
    if not i % 1000:
        fout.flush()
    if row_delim in line and i:
        fout.write('"%s"\r\n'%'","'.join(write_buffer))
        write_buffer = []
    else:
        write_buffer.append(line.strip())
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, while using .readline() is not a bad thing don't use .readlines() which will go and read the entire content of the file into a list containing each line which is incredibly inefficient.  Using the built in iterator that comes with a file object is the best memory usage and speed.

Answer (score 1):

@Constatin suggests that if you would be satisfied with replacing

```
'<><><><><><><>\n'
```

by

```
'"             \n'
```

then the replacement string is the same length, and in that case you can craft a solution to in-place editing with `mmap`. You will need python 2.6.  It's vital that the file is opened in the right mode!

```
import mmap, os
CHUNK = 2**20

oldStr = ''
newStr = '"             '
strLen = len(oldStr)
assert strLen==len(newStr)

f = open("myfilename", "r+")
size = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size

for offset in range(0,size,CHUNK):
    map = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(),
                    length=min(CHUNK+strLen,size-offset),  # not beyond EOF
                    offset=offset)
    index = 0  # start at beginning
    while 1:
        index = map.find(oldStr,index) # find next match
        if index == -1:  # no more matches in this map
            break
        map[index:index+strLen] = newStr

f.close()
```

This code is not debugged!  It works for me on a 3 MB test case, but it *may not* work on a large ( > 2GB) file - the `mmap` module still seems a bit immature, so I wouldn't rely on it too much.

Looking at the bigger picture, from what you've posted it isn't clear that your file will end up as valid CSV.  Also be aware that the tool you're planning to use to actually process the CSV may be flexible enough to deal with the file as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

[For the problem exactly as stated] There's no way that this can be done without copying the data, in python or any other language.  If your processing always replaced substrings with new substrings of *equal length*, maybe you could do it in-place.  But whenever you replace `<><><><><><><>` with `"` you are changing the position of all subsequent characters in the file.  Copying from one place to another is the only way to handle this.

EDIT:

Note that the use of `sed` won't actually save any copying...sed doesn't really edit in-place either. From the [GNU sed manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Invoking-sed.html#fn-1):

> -i[SUFFIX]
> --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>     This option specifies that files are to be edited in-place. GNU sed does this by *creating a temporary file* and sending output to this file rather than to the standard output.

(emphasis mine.)

Comment: well in csv if I include something inside "" then the spaces will be included in the field. I guess copying the data is the only way to go

Answer (score 0):

If you're delimiting fields with double quotes, it looks like you need to escape the double quotes you have occurring in your elements (for example `1231214 ""` will need to be `\n1231214 \"\"`).

Something like

```
fin = open("input", "r")
fout = open("output", "w")
for line in fin:
   if line.contains("<><><><><><><>"):
      fout.writeline("\"")
   else:
      fout.writeline(line.replace('"',r'\"')
fin.close()
fout.close()
```